# running issue TypeError: 'module' object is not callable i cant understand why this is happening please

Tags: python

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable i cant understand why this is happening please help im not sure if when im call from the superclass its not reading the subclass its said its not being called

```
import RetailItem
import CashRegister

def main():
    #info1 = ['Jacket', '12', '59.95']
    #info2 = ['Designer', '40', '34.95']
    #info3 = ['Shirt', '20', '24.95']

    print ('there are three items')
    info1 = str(input('whats the description'))
    info2 = str(input('whats the units'))
    info3 = str(input('whats the price'))

    info4 = str(input('whats the description'))
    info5 = str(input('whats the units'))
    info6 = str(input('whats the price'))

    info7 = str(input('whats the description'))
    info8 = str(input('whats the units'))
    info9 = str(input('whats the price'))


    first = CashRegister.RetailItem(info1,info2,info3)
    second = CashRegister.RetailItem(info4,info5,info6)
    third = CashRegister.RetailItem(info7,info8,info9)

    #first1 = CashRegister.CashRegister(info1[0],info1[1],info1[2])
    print ("Description       Units in Inventory          Price\n")


    #print(first.show_items())


    print (first.__str__())
    print (second.__str__())
    print (third.__str__())



#main function
```

Comment: Please show us the complete error that python prints. Copy paste it and all details it provides. Also it would be helpful to see CashRegister.py

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that RetailItem is a module and you can't call it like a function, which is what you are doing here:

```
CashRegister.RetailItem(info1,info2,info3)
```

"Calling it like a function" means you are writing (...) after a name. Here is your import statement:

```
import RetailItem
```

So you should recognize that RetailItem is a module.  If there is a function named do_stuff() defined inside the RetailItem module, then you can call it like this:

```
val = RetailItem.do_stuff()
```

On the other hand, if RetailItem is a function defined inside the CashRegister module, then all you have to do is this:

```
import CashRegister


val = CashRegister.RetailItem(...)
```

RetailItem actually looks like it's a class, but creating objects in python is just like calling a function.

Comment: here is the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\assignment\_Beginning Python\Brown_Sherdon_Ch11part2\7.cashRegister.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\assignment\_Beginning Python\Brown_Sherdon_Ch11part2\7.cashRegister.py", line 20, in main
    first = CashRegister.RetailItem(info1,info2,info3)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: A module is just a file with some python code in it.  You can define functions in a module.  To call a function defined inside a module you precede it with the module name, e.g. MyModule.myfunc().  You are responsible for knowing what functions are defined inside a module that you import.  We can't help you with that.  Just trying to guess what is defined inside a module is fruitless:  import SomeModule; #Hey I wonder if there is a function called icabodCrane() in that module:  print SomeModule.icabodCrane().  That is what you appear to be doing.

Comment: By the way, you can always open a module(which again is just a file with some python code in it) in a text editor, and LOOK at the file, and SEE what functions are defined in the module, and then KNOW which functions you can call in the module.

Answer (score 0):

`module` means you only imported the python file, but not necessarily anything in it. If you have a class inside the file that's named the same as your Python file, you would have to do `from RetailItem import RetailItem`. It's a weird one for first-timers.